# Problem to create a user interface with different windows

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am working on a project and I have to create a user interface using Python.

I decided to use Tkinter, especially as we can create python code easily from the figma website.

I have created the 2 classes for my window_1 and window_2.

I have also created buttons, on the left of the interface, it's going to be the different sections of my dashboard.

I don't really know how to define a class to manage the navigation between the different window (now there is only window_1 and window_2 but there gonna be 5 windows).

I'd like to create functions that allows when you click on the menu - button 2 to go window_2, without deleting the information in the window_1 (so I guess we should just hide it). The problem is that I have to define the different windows instance, without opening them (so we remove the .mainloop) but as my code is built, I only have one Tk() created in the class window_structure, but  I guess that's not the good way to create different windows and navigate through them.

I hope I was clear, if you can help me I'd be very happy! Thanks a lot

Arnaud

I tried different things explained below because that was the content of my problem

Here the code:

```
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

class window_structure:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window=self.create_root()

    def upload_csv_file(self):
        # Cette fonction sera appelée lorsque l'utilisateur clique sur le bouton "Upload File"
        self.filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("CSV files", "*.csv")])  # Ouvre une fenêtre pour sélectionner un fichier
        if self.filepath:  # Vérifie si un fichier a été sélectionné
            print(f"Le fichier {self.filepath} a été sélectionné.")
        else:
            print("Aucun fichier n'a été sélectionné.")

    def go_to_images_files(self, name_file: str, name_image: str) -> Path:
        return Path(__file__).parent / Path(name_file) / Path(name_image)
    
    def create_menu_buttons(self,name_file,window):

            self.button_image_1 = PhotoImage(
                file=self.go_to_images_files(name_file, "button_1.png"))

            self.button_1 = Button(
                window,
                image=self.button_image_1,
                borderwidth=0,
                highlightthickness=0,
                command=self.upload_csv_file,
                relief="flat"
            )

            self.button_1.place(
                x=43.0,
                y=167.0,
                width=186.0,
                height=80.0
            )
    
            self.button_image_2 = PhotoImage(file=self.go_to_images_files(name_file,"button_2.png"))
            
            self.button_2 = Button(
                window,
                image=self.button_image_2,
                borderwidth=0,
                highlightthickness=0,
                command=lambda:print(1),
                relief="flat"
            )
            
            self.button_2.place(
                x=43.0,
                y=31.0,
                width=186.0,
                height=80.0
            )
        
    def create_root(self):
        return Tk()
    
    def create_canvas(self,window,title):
            window.geometry("957x686")
            window.title(title)
            window.configure(bg="#189393")

            self.canvas = Canvas(
                window,
                bg="#189393",
                height=686,
                width=957,
                bd=0,
                highlightthickness=0,
                relief="ridge"
            )

            self.canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(
                0.0,
                0.0,
                271.0,
                686.0,
                fill="#791010",
                outline="")

            self.canvas.create_text(
                502.0,
                14.0,
                anchor="nw",
                text="DASHBOARD",
                fill="#FFFFFF",
                font=("Inter Bold", 45 * -1)
            )
       
class window_1:
    def __init__(self):
    
        self.window=Toplevel(Interface_structure.main_window)
        self.canvas=Interface_structure.create_canvas(self.window,"UPLOAD")
        self.name_file="WINDOW_1"
        Interface_structure.create_menu_buttons(self.name_file,self.window)
        self.create_images()
        self.create_entries()
        self.window.resizable(False, False)
        self.window.mainloop()
        
    def create_images(self):
        
        self.image_image_1 = PhotoImage(
            file=Interface_structure.go_to_images_files(self.name_file, "image_1.png"))

        self.image_1 = Interface_structure.canvas.create_image(
            428.0,
            205.0,
            image=self.image_image_1
        )
    
    def create_entries(self):

        self.entry_image_1 = PhotoImage(
        file=Interface_structure.go_to_images_files(self.name_file,"entry_1.png"))
        
        self.entry_1 = Entry(
            bd=0,
            bg="#FFFFFF",
            fg="#000716",
            highlightthickness=0
        )
        self.entry_1.place(
            x=518.0,
            y=327.0,
            width=129.0,
            height=46.0
        )
        
        self.entry_bg_1 = Interface_structure.canvas.create_image(
            582.5,
            351.0,
            image=self.entry_image_1
        ) 

class window_2:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.window=Toplevel(Interface_structure.main_window)
        self.canvas=Interface_structure.create_canvas(self.window,"FEUILLE 2")
        self.name_file="WINDOW_1"
        Interface_structure.create_menu_buttons(self.name_file,self.window)
        self.create_images()
        self.create_entries()
        self.window.resizable(False, False)
        self.window.mainloop()

    def create_images(self):
        
        self.image_image_1 = PhotoImage(
            file=Interface_structure.go_to_images_files(self.name_file, "image_1.png"))

        self.image_1 = Interface_structure.canvas.create_image(
            428.0,
            205.0,
            image=self.image_image_1
        )
    
    def create_entries(self):

        self.entry_image_1 = PhotoImage(
        file=Interface_structure.go_to_images_files(self.name_file,"entry_1.png"))
        
        self.entry_1 = Entry(
            bd=0,
            bg="#FFFFFF",
            fg="#000716",
            highlightthickness=0
        )
        self.entry_1.place(
            x=518.0,
            y=327.0,
            width=129.0,
            height=46.0
        )
        
        self.entry_bg_1 = Interface_structure.canvas.create_image(
            582.5,
            351.0,
            image=self.entry_image_1
        ) 

Interface_structure=window_structure()

#A=window_1()
#B=window_2()
```

Comment: you should have only one `mainloop()`. `Toplevel` doesn't need to run `mainloop()`.

Comment: Maybe you should create only one window - `Tk()` - and use `Frame()` to group widgets and replace frames in main window. `frame.pack()` to show it in window, and `frame.pack_forget()` to remove it from window (without deleting instance), and later again `frame.pack()` to show it again in window. [python - Switch between two frames in tkinter? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter/7557028#7557028)

Comment: Okay thanks, I've tried but I don't really know how to use correctly the frames, it's a bit messy with my code structure, any advices ?

Comment: line 99, in __init__
    self.canvas=Interface_structure.create_canvas(self.window,"UPLOAD")
NameError: name 'Interface_structure' is not defined

Comment: @Arnaud Patrick DA SILVA. Please see furas's comment.